# PageMenu framework 2.0.0 not getting installed

Tags: objective-c, swift, cocoapods, xcode8

I am trying to integrate Pagemenu framework .
Its latest version in GitHub is 2.0.0 with swift support. But whenever I do pod update its **Using PageMenu (1.2.9)** and its causing 117 errors. I am using latest Xcode version 8.3.3 and deployment target 8.0 in my Objective C Project.Please help me.

Below was the error I was getting on updating Pod with 2.0.0

[!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:

- `PageMenu (= 2.0.0)` required by `Podfile`

Specs satisfying the `PageMenu (= 2.0.0)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.